# How can I clone microsoft chart control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, clone

What's the recommended way of cloning an object of Microsoft Chart Control? Because it is a third-party library, I can't use the solution [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp) as I can't mark the object as serializable.

Preferably, I would not like to introduce any third party controls to clone the chart unless if it is absolutely impossible to do so without one.

Comment: Why do you need to clone the chart?

Comment: @EricBrown I'm implementing a feature where a user can double click an existing chart to produce a "Detail view" on it, meaning that I first need to get an identical copy of the existing chart then add/modify properties on the cloned chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not need to mark it as serializable as the charts already have the ability to be serialized. Check out this [MS Charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456693.aspx) Documentation for more information

From here, you can serialize the chart into a string, then immediately deserialize the string into a new instance of the chart object. This would act similarly to cloning, and appears to be what the answer mentioned in your quesiton is doing.  It is probably not the most efficient method for doing this, but it will work

**EDIT**

This code is unteseted but should work (Be fairly accurate for how to accomplish this)

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();
//Enter your chart building code here
System.IO.MemoryStream myStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
Chart chart2 = new Chart();
chart1.Serializer.Save(myStream);
chart2.Serializer.Load(myStream);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but.. what does this have to do with cloning?

Comment: Updated the answer, realized that I was misunderstanding the question

Comment: My god, such a simple method! Thank you very much.

Comment: Amazing, Simple and accurate.

Comment: After my chart was copied to stream adding new points to series did not update xaxis min and max. They returned NaN, Could not find out why so it was fixed checking if min value was NaN and in that case calling chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answer your question but it could help you in implementing your feature.You could use the `Drill Down` feature of `Chart` control to produce a detailed view  of the part of the chart the user has clicked. Refer the [samples environment](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) of mschart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I still need to clone the chart for other reasons besides detail view, it just happens to be one of them.